# Clutch issue in 1995 Mazda Miata

Tags: transmission, clutch, mazda, clutch-cylinder, miata

My clutch pedal had absolutely no pressure unless I would pump it, but that wouldn't do much. It finally gave out so I changed the master cylinder next to the break cylinder with one that I know works for sure. It did, but when I woke up the next day I had absolutely no pressure at all. I know I don't have a leak because there's no fluid coming out of anywhere. What are my other options that it could be?

Comment: When you changed out the master cylinder, did you also change out the slave? If not, how well did you bleed the hydraulics?

Comment: Yeah i never realized the bleeder on the slave and i blend it through there yeaterday and now its working great thank u for the quick response this website is awsome

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the answer was to bleed the master/slave hydraulics.

Comment: If this helped and answered your question, please consider selecting it as the answer (check mark below the up/down vote).